# Selecting the latest row for each customer that matches these params

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an SQL table that stores reports. Each row has a customer_id and a building_id and when I have the customer_id, I need to select the latest row (most recent create_date) for each building with that customer_id.

```
report_id    customer_id    building_id    create_date
1            1              4              1553561789
2            2              5              1553561958
3            1              4              1553561999
4            2              5              1553562108
5            3              7              1553562755
6            3              8              1553570000
```

I would expect to get report id's 3, 4, 5 and 6 back.

How do I query this? I have tried a few sub-selects and group by and not gotten it to work.

Comment: You never showed us the sixth row.  Also, why is row #2 not being returned, given that it has a unique `(customer_id, building_id)` combination?

Comment: I added a 6th row.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySQL 8+, then `ROW_NUMBER` is a good approach here:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id, building_id
                                 ORDER BY create_date DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT
    report_id,
    customer_id,
    building_id,
    create_date
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

If there could be more than one customer/building pair tied for the latest creation date, and you want to capture all ties, then replace `ROW_NUMBER` with `RANK`, and use the same query.

Comment: How do I only pull for a specific customer_id, one row for each building, the latest?

Comment: @Ping Remove `building_id` from the `PARTITION` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Another variation:

```
SELECT a.*
  FROM myTable a
  WHERE a.create_date = (SELECT MAX(create_date)
                           FROM myTable b
                           WHERE b.customer_id = a.customer_id
                             AND b.building_id = a.building_id)
```

Can try doing a search for "effective dated records" to see various approaches.

Comment: That's kind of what I started with and I get an error but can't see the issue.

Comment: $sql = "SELECT a.* FROM nf_report a WHERE a.create_date = (SELECT MAX(create_date) FROM nf_report b WHERE b.customer_id = a.customer_id AND b.building_id = a.building_id";

Comment: Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 2

Comment: @Ping The query you ran is missing a closing parenthesis.  And you are not running the SQL code in this answer verbatim.

Comment: Got it, thank you. How do I limit this to just one customer_id? Where does that where clause go?

Comment: At the end seems to work, SELECT a.* FROM nf_report a WHERE a.create_date = (SELECT MAX(create_date) FROM nf_report b WHERE b.customer_id = a.customer_id AND b.building_id = a.building_id) AND customer_id = 2